# methods injected by lombok not recognized inside the same class

Tags: code-injection, netbeans-8, lombok

During a simple use of lombok, IDEs such as Netbeans, Intellij allows the use of methods injected by the library lombok for example @Getter & @Setter.

```
import lombok.Getter;

public class Test {

    @Getter
    private Double var;   

    public Double calculTva(double tva) {
        return this.getVar() * tva;
    }
}
```

The code **return this.getVar()** is not recognized by the **Test** class.
But if we use an another class, for example **Test2**, in this case we can use the **getter** method.

```
public class Test2 {     

    public Double calculTva(double tva) {
        Test t =new Test();
        return t.getVar() * tva;
    }
}
```

Environnement :

1. Netbeans 8.0.2
2. lombok 1.16.13
3. Jdk 1.7
4. Project type **Java application**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your NetBeans IDE, follow this instructions :

1. Open your poject
2. Project properties
3. Build / Compiling / **Enable annotation processing**
4. Change to **true** (chechk it) the value of **Enable Annotation Processing in Editor**.
5. Save & test

Answer (score 0):

In Intellij, add lombok plug-in in addition to lombok dependency.